# nodejs oracledb externalAuth (using oracle wallet)

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb, oracle-wallet

In this sample nodejs app I am trying to connect to oracle database with a wallet. The wallet is created in the server, and, the contents of the wallet directory was zipped and unzipped into my project's root folder (inside a folder called `wallet`).

Further included `sqlnet.ora` file in the same folder. Its contents are:

```
WALLET_LOCATION=

(SOURCE=

(METHOD=FILE)

(METHOD_DATA=

(DIRECTORY=D:\code\js\myoracledb-app\wallet)

)

)
```

The main program (`index.js`) is pretty straight forward:

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const path = require('path');
const configDir = path.join(__dirname, 'wallet');
// oracledb.initOracleClient({ configDir: configPath });
// oracledb.initOracleClient();
const poolOptions = {  
  externalAuth: true,
  connectionString: '8.83.87.12:1522/ORCLCDB',
  configDir  
};

oracledb.createPool(poolOptions, function(err, pool){
  if(err) {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
  else {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, conn){
      if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        process.exit(2);
      }
      else {
        conn.execute('select sysdate from dual', [], {}, function(err, result){
          if(err) {
            console.error(err);
            process.exit(3);
          }
          else {
            
            conn.release(function(){
              console.log('Result:', JSON.stringify(result));
              process.exit(0);
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

I have used `oracledb` as the client to connect to my remote database. I get an error in the callback for `pool.getConnection()`. This is verified by the error code returned.

The error output to console is:

```
[Error: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied] {
  errorNum: 1017,
  offset: 0
}
```

I have tried various of trying to initialize the oracledb client (`oracledb.initOraClient()`), but, the result is the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Ps: if interested in how the wallet was created read [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282458/logon-denied-for-oracle-wallet-user) post and its comments.

Comment: Does the wallet contain the DB username and password? Not all do.  For example the wallets for Oracle Cloud Autonomous DBs do not.  See https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/how-connect-to-oracle-autonomous-cloud-databases

Comment: Get it working with SQL*Plus first and then it will work with node-oracledb - they both use the same internal library APIs.  This will let more people help you, and you will be able to work with Oracle Support too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted the `sqlnet.ora` as follows:

```
WALLET_LOCATION=

(SOURCE=

(METHOD=FILE)

(METHOD_DATA=

(DIRECTORY=D:\code\js\myoracledb-app\wallet)

)

)

SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE=TRUE
```

Next, the pool options were defined as follows:

```js
const poolOptions = {  
  externalAuth: true,
  connectionString: 'ORCLCDB'
};
```

The `ORCLCDB` service name was defined in the `tnsnames.ora`.

```
ORCLCDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
     (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <host_ip_or_name>)(PORT = <server_port>))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
     (SERVICE_NAME =ORCLCDB)
    )    
   )
```

Both `sqlnet.ora` and `tnsnames.ora` file was placed in the wallet folder. Set `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable to the wallet folder. Here is an example of how to do that in powershell:

```
PS1 > $env:TNS_ADMIN=$(join-path $pwd wallet)
```